# python equivalent of (process.env.PORT || 3000)

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

I don't know if this is the best place to ask but wanted to know what the `python` equivalent to `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;` is?

The main purpose being I want to be able to set environment variables in python depending on the environment

Comment: See [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os.environ.get('PORT', 3000)`. The `os.environ` map supports the `.get` method, which returns the value if the key is present, otherwise the second argument is returned.

```
~$ PORT=4000 python

>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)
'4000'
```

You might want to wrap the command in `int` to get an int regardless of whether the environment variable or the default value is used, but the behaviour will be the same as in your Javascript example.